# limit with e and double powers (using L'Hospital's rule)

Tags: calculus

I have to solve:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left({e^{-x^-2}\over x^{100}}\right)$$

I tried to do this as follows:

top part is: $e^{-1/x^2}$ which should become 0 (according to wolramalpha)? I would solve this as $e^{0^{-2}}$ and $0{^{-2}}$ is not determined? because it equals $1\over0^{-2} $.
not sure how to solve this.

bottom part would be: $0^{100}$ which is 0.

Then you derive the top and bottom part and solve $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left({{2e^{-x^-2}\over x^{3}}\over 100x^{99} }\right)$$

which simplifies to $$\lim_{x\to 0}\left({e^{-x^-2}\over 50x^{102} }\right)$$

but then I get the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: make a change of variable $u = x^{-2}, x^{102} = u^{-51}$ **or** $u = x^2, x^{102} = u^{51}$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $y = \dfrac1{x^2}$.
Then
$\lim_{x\to 0}\left({e^{-x^-2}\over x^{100}}\right)
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\left({e^{-y}\over y^{-50}}\right)
=\lim_{y\to \infty}\dfrac{y^{50}}{e^{y}}
$.

You can now apply
L'Hopital's rule
50 times,
or do this:

Watch carefully:
since,
from the power series for
$e^y$,
$e^y
> \dfrac{y^{51}}{51!}$,
so
$\dfrac{y^{50}}{e^y}
< \dfrac{51!}{y}
\to 0
$.